# Errors in conditional return type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that accepts "value" and then, depending it true or false should return 0 or 1.

[Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAFRgUwB5U2AEwhgCMQQAbTAQzAD4AKAN2ooFdMAuGNASm7isImLLnxEeMAPwwADDG4BGJHRgBvAFAwYASwTNWHJImSCKw3jABOmKGytg5Abi1ZzIm3YcxFLgL5OQA)

```js
const f = <T extends boolean>(value: T): false extends T ? 0 : 1 => {
  if (value === false) return 0;
  else return 1;
};
```

However, I get an error from TS saying in both "return" cases:
`Type '0' is not assignable to type 'false extends T ? 0 : 1'`

Are there any possible approaches for this without using 'as' operator?

Comment: Assigning to a conditional type is really hard for the Typescript compiler to do. It's best avoided, IMHO. Would overloads meet your needs? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&target=99&jsx=0&module=1&isolatedModules=false&ts=4.9.5#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhACgG4EMA2YCmAXKrgM74CUxADKJLIiutnkcjAE4FXICMwdaPCSpMuAsQBGCBDnxYIPasgA+fZAG9gyZHBDIxrZAF5TJHOQrIO+GGA4pqAbm3J8F-Ndv2UvFwF8BKCRSGGQsE1FObmAAelidHQA9AH4gkLDJSPQQMko4hMTUoA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When faced with these kinds of problems, I always move the signature into an overload:

```
function f<T extends boolean>(value: T): T extends false ? 0 : 1;
function f(value: boolean) {
    if (value === false) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

This is utilizing the fact that TypeScript does not check if the implementation "matches" the overloads, it only checks if the overloads are assignable to the function declaration's signature (here, it is `(value: boolean) => 0 | 1`).

Note that this still does not type-check the implementation. You can swap `0` and `1` in the body and it'll still work, but that would be the same case when using the `as` operator anyways.

This also requires you to use function declarations and not function expressions, since overloads are not supported for function expressions (see [ms/TS#16731](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16731)).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAPAFUQUwB5U2AEwGdEAjOOAG0wEMwA+ACgDcbKRMAuRNASm4w48hEsDZFMiAPyIADIm4BGANwAoUJFgJkLNh27kqtML0QBvVYiuIYwRLvaSAvC+TjMpgE6YoIT0lk1ayxKCURvX39EFVUAX1UgA)

---

As @AlexWayne points out in a comment, you could also use 2 overloads and get rid of the conditional type:

```
function f(value: true): 1;
function f(value: false): 0;
function f(value: boolean) {
    if (value === false) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

This still has the drawbacks I mentioned earlier, however, but one problem is that if you pass something of type `boolean`, you get an error, since no overloads match. You can of course, just add another overload (at the *bottom*, since it's the least specific):

```
function f(value: true): 1;
function f(value: false): 0;
function f(value: boolean): 0 | 1;
function f(value: boolean) {
    if (value === false) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFANwIYBsQFMBciUATngJSECMA3AFCiSwLLrZ6HDYDOuFiADHQbR4SVJhwFEAIzhwsuDGDKIA3rUSbEMYIlaTEAXmPJuvRMVxQQxJII1bcWHhas2kNWgF8gA)

---

One flaw with using `T extends false ? 0 : 1` or `false extends T ? 0 : 1` is that when `T` is `boolean`, then the type is either `1` or `0` (respectively), instead of the more sensible `0 | 1`. Fixing this would require you to check if it's the general `boolean` type first, which lengthens things quite a bit:

```
boolean extends T ? 0 | 1 : T extends false ? 0 : 1
```